# Laravel scope active on post show

Tags: php, laravel

I have scope on model post:

```
public function scopeActive($query) {
    return $query->where('active', true);
}
```

On PostController I have method show:

```
public function show(Post $post) {
   //
}
```

How I can attach scope to show method and do `abort(404)` on not active posts? I need do this globally. If I add global scope, then users can't edit their posts, if post not active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the resolution logic by placing this in your RouteServiceProvider's `boot` method:

```
Route::bind('post', function ($id) {
    return App\Post::active()->find($id) ?? abort(404);
});
```

Comment: Yep. You could also do `Route::bind('activePost', ...)` and use `{activePost}` in routes that should have only active posts available to them. This leaves `{post}` unmodified, for something like (for example) admin routes that should have access to inactive ones.

Comment: I think laravel will do the 404 for you if you to `Post::active()->findOrFail($id)`

Comment: @ceejayoz Cat5InTheCradle you are both correct, thanks for the added tips!

Comment: @Jeff so, when I edit shop I get error 404. When remove route::bind all good, how I can remove this scope for edit posts?

Comment: @Jeff can you please give a example?